# Resources getting deleted when trying to add at run time

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, resources

When i am trying to add resources to another file at run time, some of the earlier resources are getting deleted. Please find the source code below:

```
    void CResourceIncludeSampleDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{


    CString strInputFile = _T("C:\\SampleData\\FileToInsert.zip"); // This File is 100 MB

    HANDLE hFile   = CreateFile(strInputFile, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    DWORD FileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

    BYTE *pBuffer = new BYTE[FileSize];
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    ReadFile(hFile, pBuffer, FileSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL);

    for (int iIndex = 1; iIndex <= 4; iIndex++)
    {
        InsertResource(FileSize, iIndex, pBuffer);
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}

void CResourceIncludeSampleDlg::InsertResource(DWORD FileSize, int iIndex, BYTE *pBuffer)
{
    CString strOutputFile = _T("C:\\SampleData\\ResourceIncludeSample_Source.exe");
    int iResourceID = 300 + iIndex;

    HANDLE hResource = BeginUpdateResource(strOutputFile, FALSE);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hResource)
    {
        if (UpdateResource(hResource, _T("VIDEOBIN"), MAKEINTRESOURCE(iResourceID), MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),
                           (LPVOID)pBuffer, FileSize) == TRUE)
        {
            EndUpdateResource(hResource, FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

After completion of the execution, i am expecting output as 301, 302, 303 and 304 added under "VIDEOBIN" category. But only 2 (sometimes 3) resources are present. One resource is always deleted.

Could you please let me know what could be wrong or any fix for the same ?
Any help or sample source code is greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
YKK Reddy

Answer (score 0):

You need `delete[] pBuffer` after closing the file. It should be `RT_RCDATA` instead of `_T("VIDEOBIN")` although custom resource name may not be the cause of this particular problem.